# R: `Error in f(x): could not find function "f"` when trying to use column of functions as argument in a tibble

Tags: r, functional-programming, purrr, magrittr

I'm experimenting with using functions in dataframes (tidyverse tibbles) in R and I ran into some difficulties. The following is a minimal (trivial) example of my problem.

Suppose I have a function that takes in three arguments: `x` and `y` are numbers, and `f` is a function. It performs `f(x) + y` and returns the output:

```
func_then_add = function(x, y, f) {
  result = f(x) + y
  return(result)
}
```

And I have some simple functions it might use as `f`:

```
squarer = function(x) {
  result = x^2
  return(result)
}

cuber = function(x) {
  result = x^3
  return(result)
}
```

Done on its own, `func_then_add` works as advertised:

```
> func_then_add(5, 2, squarer)
[1] 27
> func_then_add(6, 11, cuber)
[1] 227
```

But lets say I have a dataframe (tidyverse tibble) with two columns for the numeric arguments, and one column for which function I want:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)

test_frame = tribble(
  ~arg_1, ~arg_2, ~func,
  5, 2, squarer,
  6, 11, cuber
)

> test_frame
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  arg_1 arg_2 func  
  <dbl> <dbl> <list>
1     5     2 <fn>  
2     6    11 <fn>
```

I then want to make another column `result` that is equal to `func_then_add` applied to those three columns. It should be `27` and `227` like before. But when I try this, I get an error:

```
> test_frame %>% mutate(result=func_then_add(.$arg_1, .$arg_2, .$func))
Error in f(x) : could not find function "f"
```

Why does this happen, and how do I get what I want properly? I confess that I'm new to "functional programming", so maybe I'm just making an obvious syntax error ...

Comment: I think you might need to take  a look at `force`..

Comment: Can you elaborate please? @NelsonGon

Comment: Disregard my earlier comment, it's useless since you already have squarer and cuber.

Comment: So what do I do instead? :s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the most elegant but we can do:

```
test_frame %>% 
  mutate(Res= map(seq_along(.$func), function(x)
        func_then_add(.$arg_1, .$arg_2, .$func[[x]])))
```

**EDIT**: The above `map`s both over the entire data which isn't really what OP desires. As suggested by @January this can be better applied as:

```
Result <- test_frame %>% 
  mutate(Res= map(seq_along(.$func), function(x)
       func_then_add(.$arg_1[x], .$arg_2[x], .$func[[x]])))

Result$Res
```

The above again is not very efficient since it returns a list. A better alternative(again as suggested by @January is to use `map_dbl` which returns the same data type as its objects:

```
test_frame %>% 
   mutate(Res= map_dbl(seq_along(.$func), function(x)
       func_then_add(.$arg_1[x], .$arg_2[x], .$func[[x]])))
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  arg_1 arg_2 func     Res
  <dbl> <dbl> <list> <dbl>
1     5     2 <fn>      27
2     6    11 <fn>     227
```

Comment: I think it should be `.$arg_1[x]` and `.$arg_2[x]`, otherwise you are calling `func_then_add` with two vector arguments of length 2 and map returns two numbers for each row. Also, use `map_dbl` and not `map`, because `map` returns a list and you get a list column.

Comment: Yes @January you're right. It's something I was trying to correct. Thanks, I have edited to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you should map instead of mutating. Mutate calls the function once, and supplies the whole columns as arguments.

The second problem is that `test_frame$func[1]` is not a function, but a list with one element. You can't have "function" columns, only list columns.

Try this:

```
test_frame$result <- with(test_frame, 
          map_dbl(1:2, ~ func_then_add(arg_1[.], arg_2[.], func[[.]])))
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  arg_1 arg_2 func   result
  <dbl> <dbl> <list>  <dbl>
1     5     2 <fn>       27
2     6    11 <fn>      227
```

**EDIT**: a simpler solution using dplyr, mutate and rowwise:

```
test_frame %>% rowwise %>% mutate(res=func_then_add(arg_1, arg_2, func))
```

Quite frankly, I am slightly puzzled by this last one. Why `func` and not `func[[1]]`? `func` should be a list, and not function. `mutate` and `rowwise` are doing here something sinister, like automatically converting a list to a vector.

**Edit 2**: actually, this is written explicitly in the `rowwise` manual:

> Its main impact is to allow you to work with list-variables in
>   ‘summarise()’ and ‘mutate()’ without having to use ‘[[1]]’.

**Final edit:** I became so fixated on tidyverse recently that I did not think of the simplest option – using base R:

```
apply(test_frame, 1, function(x) func_then_add(x$arg_1, x$arg_2, x$func))
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I hadn't heard of the `rowwise` function before. Looking at the documentation, it's some kind of grouping operation? Does I need to append a `%>% ungroup()` or `%>% as_tibble()` or something afterwards? Anyway it looks like this is all quite a bit more complicated than I thought ...

Comment: Yes, this is the case (add `%>% ungroup` if necessary). Yeah, this things are sometimes complicated to wrap your mind around. I find tidyverse sometimes fairly unintuitive.

Comment: P.S. if calling a function without arguments, no need to use the `()`; saves you 2 microseconds of typing ;-)